# Pointer for ROM variable in a RAM variable?

Tags: c, mplab-c18

I'm doing a project using the Microchip C18 compiler. I have a struct called a block that points to other blocks (north east south west). These blocks will make me a map.
I then have a pointer that I use to evaluate everything.

Just using RAM it looks like:

```
struct block{
        struct block *north;
        struct block *east;
        struct block *south;
        struct block *west;
};


struct block map[5] =
{ // just a simple line.
        { NULL, &map[1], NULL, NULL },
        { NULL, &map[2], NULL, &map[0]},
        { NULL, &map[3], NULL, &map[2]},
        { NULL, &map[4], NULL, &map[3]},
        { NULL, NULL, NULL, &map[4]}
};


struct block* position = &map[0];
```

This lets me do stuff like:

```
void goWest()
{
if(position -> west != NULL) position = position -> west;
}
```

Problem is that I've run out of RAM in my project and need to use ROM
What I have so far is:

```
struct block{
        rom struct block *north;
        rom struct block *east;
        rom struct block *south;
        rom struct block *west;
};
rom struct block map[5] =
{ // just a simple line.
        { NULL, &map[1], NULL, NULL },
        { NULL, &map[2], NULL, &map[0]},
        { NULL, &map[3], NULL, &map[2]},
        { NULL, &map[4], NULL, &map[3]},
        { NULL, NULL, NULL, &map[4]}
};
```

I've done some debugging and can tell the above part works, but trying to make the position pointer is giving me grief.
so I guess my question is:

How do I hold the ROM variable addresses in a pointer which I can edit the values of?

When i try:

```
struct block *position = &map[0];
```

I get "Warning [2066] type qualifier mismatch in assignment"

I realize that a ROM variable and RAM variable are two different things,
but I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Hi Cal Pratt, and welcome. I've done a few small edits on your text, you might want to take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the definition of the `rom` macro?  I'm guessing that it expands to `const` (and possibly a compiler-specific `__attribute__` or somesuch), because the compiler is complaining about a "type qualifier mismatch", which refers to a `const` or `volatile` mismatch.

What that means is that you're trying to implicitly cast a pointer to constant data into a pointer to non-constant data.  This code should generate the same warning with your compiler:

```
const int x = 0;
int *y = &x;  // &x is "pointer to const" but y is "pointer to non-const"
```

To fix it, you need to declare that your `position` pointer is a pointer to constant data (which, depending on the definition of the `rom` macro, should be done with either `rom` or the `const` qualifier):

```
// Declare a non-constant pointer to constant data
const struct block *position = &map[0];
```

At each pointer level, you can have a `const` qualifier or lack thereof, and likewise for the base non-pointer object.  So, a single-level pointer can have 4 different variants:

```
int *x;  // Non-constant pointer to non-constant data
int *const x;  // Constant pointer to non-constant data
const int *x;  // Non-constant pointer to constant data
int const *x;  // Same as above
const int *const x;  // Constant pointer to constant data
int const *const x;  // Same as above
```

Note that `int const` and `const int` are equivalent, but otherwise the placement of `const` *does* matter.

Comment: The Microchip PIC uses a Harvard architecture -- ROM and RAM are in completely separate address spaces, so you can't mix pointers to the two. I believe they're using a custom type qualifier to separate the two.

Comment: @duskwuff: Ah ok, I wasn't aware of that.  In that case, just replace `const` with `rom` in all of the above, and it should still apply, assuming that the compiler is reasonably behaved.  So `rom struct block *position = &map[0];` should be the correct definition.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: Thanks, that solved it!! 
I was so sure I tried doing that and it had failed :/ guess I should sleep soon haha.